# mongodb:find query on case insensitive index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My collection is:

```
{ "Name" : "Bhanu"}
```

when i execute the below query, will it returns the above doc(`"Name" : "Bhanu"`)?

```
db.coll.find({"Name" : "BHANU"}).collation({ locale: 'en', strength: 2  })
```

Surprisingly it was returning the result (`"Name" : "Bhanu"`) even though that i passed the parameter in upper or lower case like "BHANU" or "bhanu" .

My question is, how come that i was getting the result without creating the case insensitive index ? Can someone explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What indexes you have, and where is your aggregation?

Comment: i have only one index which is for _id (auto created) and i m not using any aggregation query. Just using the normal find query which i stated in the above question.

Comment: Why on the Earth you are asking about indexes and tag it as an aggregation question then? Please have a read [how to ask to get an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and may be [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.collation/)

Comment: As Alex stated, the documentation does cover this. The answers could be clearer on this but hey, not all answers are submitted by someone with a deep understanding of the issue. And they do "point to the documentation", so I'm not picking nits. Indexes are "preferred" but not "mandatory". Collation is as collation does.